# where is Reads.at defined?

Tags: json, playframework

JsPath's read method is defined as

```
 def read[T](implicit r: Reads[T]): Reads[T] = Reads.at[T](this)(r)
```

Where is the source code of Reads.at? I am unable to locate it.

Answer (score 0):

found it. It is defined in JsContraints.scala

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.13/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsConstraints.scala